# Using git to store and download config files (.vimrc, &c.)

Tags: git, bash

It would be lovely if I could easily get my own `.vimrc`, `.tmux.conf`, etc when I'm working on a new machine, so my muscle memory doesn't keep betraying me by telling me the tmux prefix is `C-b`. I thought I could put those files on git and just download them onto each new machine I work on, but haven't been able to find a nice, terse, easily memorizable bash command to pull down the files.

I've tried `git clone --depth=1`, but I'm not allowed to just clone into my home directory - it's already occupied. I could download each file individually using wget or cURL but that's hardly efficient. Is there another way that would help me keep these config files centralized?

Comment: What about just cloning to a regular subfolder, and have a script to copy every file to the correct location?

Comment: I wrote a Python script (perhaps overly fancy, but it's full of protective coding) to do this for my dot-files. It is in my published scripts, along with the dot-files themselves: https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts

Comment: Seems like a dotfile manager like [yadm](https://thelocehiliosan.github.io/yadm/) might fit your need

Comment: I just include a Makefile and have an `install` target.  `(git clone url dotfiles && cd $_ && make install)`  Bothering with depth=1 for something as tiny as this takes longer to type than does downloading the extra data, even on my at-home DSL link.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I personally do to keep my dotfiles handy as I have found it to work the best for me.

- Github repo is named .dotfiles (so the directory will be hidden when I clone it).
- Inside the repo I have my configs in directories seperated by category. These file have the + symbol appended to the end of their names. (ie *vim+*, *firefox+*, *ranger+*, *i3+*, *bash+*, etc)
- I use **[stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Introduction)** to create symbolic links to the files in my home directory.

All stow does is create a symbolic link to a file in the parent directory of where you called stow from. If you pass stow a directory, it will stow everything in the directory.

Example:

If I'm in the directory (~/.dotfiles) and call `stow vim+/.vimrc` a symbolic link will be created in (~) that points to my vim config file.

I wrote a simple bash script that calls stow on every config file in a directory that has a + symbol appended to the name.

```
#!/bin/env bash
cd ~/.dotfiles;
for stowable_file in *+; do
    stow $stowable_file;
done;
cd -;
```

Here is another script that is written a little better:

```
while read -r file; do
    stow $file
done < "$(ls | grep +)"
```

Stow can do a lot more than I use it for, so I recommend checking out the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html).

For more detail you can check out my [configs](https://github.com/graysoncroom/.dotfiles).

Comment: Improvement suggestion for the first script: remove trailing semicolons and save two expensive pipes/forks with `for stowable_file in *+; do`.